# Why does returning timestamp value get bool inside useEffect in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timestamp

I am trying to get only year from timestamp values using `substring`.
The timestamp value looks like `2020-11-19T17:26:53.561Z`.
In my case, as you can see the below code, `paid_date` is the timestamp value.

```
  const invoices = [
    {paid_date: "2020-11-19T17:26:53.561Z", amount: 50},
    ...
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const new = invoices.map(invoice => ({
      paid_year: +invoice.paid_date.substr(0, 4),
      paid_month: +invoice.paid_date.substr(5, 2),
      amount: +invoice.amount
    }))

    console.log(new);
  }, [invoices, isMountedRef]);
```

I expected the paid_year like 2020 as the result, but it returns the below array.

```
0: {paid_year: 2020, paid_month: 11, amount: 240}
1: {paid_year: false, paid_month: 11, amount: 500}
2: {paid_year: false, paid_month: 11, amount: 500}
3: {paid_year: true, paid_month: 12, amount: 20}
4: {paid_year: false, paid_month: 5, amount: 10}
5: {paid_year: false, paid_month: 3, amount: 5}
...
```

Why does it return the first `paid_year` is `2020` but others are `boolean`?
I tried to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) as well as `substr`, `substring` and `slice` methods.
The weird thing is that the result was correct what I expected only few times.

**UPDATE:**
The `new` variable name is just my idea, so that's beside the point.
Same result whatever the name I used rather than `new`.

And the `invoices` is the axios api response and from my PostgreSQL database.

I am not sure if it is because of wrong usage of `useEffect`.

It worked well outside `useEffect`.

Comment: `const new`. `new`  is reserved word in js.

Comment: give an example data which return not the expected result

Comment: @AlanOmar, `new` or whatever always the same.

Comment: I don't think it's related to react, but if you can give the full `invoices`, it will help us to see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

My brother you can deal with dates in multiple ways in react. If you have lot off stuff and things to do with dates then moment.js is best package out there.

here is the link: https://momentjs.com/docs/

do install: npm install moment

here is one use case

```js
import moment from 'moment'



const invoices = [
    {paid_date: "2020-11-19T17:26:53.561Z", amount: 50},
    ...
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const new = invoices.map(invoice => ({
      paid_year: +invoice.paid_date.moment.formate('YYYY'),
      paid_month: +invoice.paid_date.moment.formate('M'),
      amount: +invoice.amount
    }))

    console.log(new);
  }, [invoices, isMountedRef]);
```

Comment: This is not what the author wants, actually.